# is this a correct method to check if a compass sensor is present on the system?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am trying to check compass sensor for so long with the given method. Please, tell me if the following is right:

```
SensorManager m = getSensorManager();
if (!m.hasSystemFeature(SensorManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_COMPASS)) {
    //
}
```

Comment: @HCK Please don't add "thanks". See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/349538).

Answer (score 3):

`FEATURE_SENSOR_COMPASS` is not a constant on `SensorManager`. It is [a constant on `PackageManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#FEATURE_SENSOR_COMPASS).

As is shown in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility#Features), you can use `PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_COMPASS` to determine if there is a magnetometer sensor (often used for implementing a compass):

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_COMPASS)) {
    // This device does not have a compass, turn off the compass feature
    disableCompassFeature();
}
```